# 389 directory server to create vlv index without stopping the server?

Tags: ldap

Do you guys happen to know a way to create vlv index for 389 directory server without stopping the server ?

according to [red hat doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.1/html/Administration_Guide/Creating_Indexes-Creating_VLV_Indexes.html), to create the vlv index, I have 2 options:

1. run script vlvindex, but it needs bring server down first.
2. create a task with nsIndexVLVAttribute attribute. (but I can not find this attribute in my 389 ds. I'm guessing this is a specific feature for redhat directory)

Do you guys know a better way to create vlv index for 389 directory server? thanks a lot